# Angular function to take row from model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularjs function whereby the hope is to take a row away from  $scope.model.insuredContact using the splice function. Unfortunately right now it seems the line of code below simply returns the row that hypothetically would be taken away...if that makes any sense? Meaning it just returns the row we are try eliminate but it doesn't really take it out of the array. How to do? Any help would be most appreciated.

```
$scope.txtChanged = function (i) {
    var x = $scope.model.insuredContact[i];

    if ((x.ContactName === '' || x.ContactName == undefined) &&  (x.ContactEmail === '' || x.ContactEmail == undefined) && (x.ContactPhone === '' || x.ContactPhone == undefined)) {
        if (i == $scope.model.insuredContact.length - 1) { return; }

        $scope.model.insuredContact = $scope.model.insuredContact.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just `splice` it.. Model and View will be updated..

Comment: `$scope.txtChanged = function (i) { $scope.model.insuredContact.splice(i, 1); };`